# wamp .htaccess in subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How do I setup a .htaccess in a wampserver?

I have this as files structure
- www

-> mypage

--> views

--> .....

And I want to rewrite the url from localhost/mypage/views/user/index.php?page=register
to
localhost/mypage/register

I already be able to achieve that. But only if I put it inside www folder of Wamp.
I don't want to put it in root of www.I want to put it in my mypage folder.

here is my rewrite rule i Used.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^woohoo/([^/.]*)$ /woohoo/views/users/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Please help me with this. I already search through the net. But they only show it to setup in www folder wamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mypage
RewriteRule ^woohoo/([^/.]*)$ /woohoo/views/users/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Put .htaccess file in `mypage`

Comment: i try to navigate localhost/woohoo/register. but 404 error. please note that there's typo there. mypage should be woohoo.

Comment: dear felipe.. I try to navigate to localhost/woohoo/woohoo/register and its working.. I already try editing the rewriterule.. but not working.. which one should I edit.. btw tq for your help..:)

Comment: its ok felipe.. i already fix this using online htaccess generator.. btw.. TQ for your help.!